# Bluetooth and Android Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

So basically (and as far as I know) an android project has some basic methods:

`OnCreate`, `OnStart`, `OnResume`, `OnPause` `OnStop` and `OnDestroy`...

I have seen this link at androids page, if I'm using the Bluetooth with the Google glass, and using it to discover surrounding devices, then list them, then pair one selected and finally send data to that one, where should each part of this code be placed?

I was thinking `OnCreate` for initialize variables and start discovering, but then? What would be the big difference of putting things at `Oncreate` or `OnStart`, or cleaning at `OnStop` or `OnDestroy`. Every time I go out of my app at Google glass the `OnDestroy` is triggered, so I get a little confused.

And still not too clear about what `OnPause` and `OnResume` do, when they happen, is the apps memory still intact?

Comment: you can see this link:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html   about Activity Lifecycle. Additionally you can do it in service that running in background and don't stop when close app.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement Bluetooth-related things in a Service so it never stops even when you are out of your Activity. Your Activity can then connect to that service in onResume and disconnect in onPause().

You could refer to the Bluetooth sample in the Android SDK to see how they do that.

Comment: No, I mean Service. You should read on Services in Android and study the BT example

Comment: OK, I'll have a look at that!